# Unique constraint with embedded schema

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Is there any way to get a unique constraint working for an embedded schema?

The given code below gives the exception:

> cannot add constraint to changeset because it does not have a source

Field `name` comes from the schema `persons` and field `email` from `accounts`

Schema:

```
embedded_schema do
    field :name
    field :email
end
```

Changeset:

```
struct
  |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, [:name, :email])
  |> Ecto.Changeset.validate_required([:name, :email])
  |> Ecto.Changeset.unique_constraint(:email)
```

I tried to give the schema `accounts` in as parameter but with no success.

Comment: Can you post the code for your module, please? Did you have to set `use App.Web, :model`?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to get a unique constraint working for an embedded schema?

The short answer is no.

Ecto's `unique_constraint` relies on the database. In order to work, you need to add unique index for the given field. The constraint will only convert the database error into a changeset error. You can read more in the docs https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#unique_constraint/3

**Edit:**

<strike>Using `embedded_schema` means that you cannot have unique index on the `email` "field", because it's not a field itself. Ecto uses a single `jsonb` field to store the embedded data.</strike>

You could create an `Account` schema which is related to the database. Then you could manually map the data to an account changeset and use `unique_constraint` on it.

Comment: It doesn't get stored as JSON. The `name` field is stored into a `persons` table, while the `email` field is stored in the `accounts` table. So I thought I could use a constraint for this. Little background information: I am trying out `insert_all`  (http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/05/ectos-insert_all-and-schemaless-queries/) therefor I made a form to create a new 'person' with some account information like `email`.

Comment: I see. Still you cannot have `unique_constraint` on this changeset because its schema is not related to the database. You could define `Account` schema and have the `unique_constraint` on the account changeset. So you'll have to manually map the data to an `account` changeset, which will use the unique constraint.

Comment: Thats what i'm going to do. But I thought there would've been a way to do it without mapping it to the `account` model/